# Burn an Ubuntu ISO on a flash drive on MacOS for a PC

Tags: iso

This question involves 3 (!) operating systems, so I hope I'm asking at the right place.

I'm trying to write an Ubuntu ISO image on a flash drive, to be used on a Lenovo PC laptop. I am using a MacOS computer to burn the ISO file with unetbootin, [following the official instructions](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-macos).

[image]

The process ends with success, but the Flash Drive is not bootable - when I choose the right option form the boot menu, it tries to read it but quickly fails back to the existing GRUB screen on the Lenovo.

Any idea what am I doing wrong? Can I write an ISO image for a PC using a Mac?

Comment: Are there any errors?

Comment: Is PC UEFI? If so you need the 64 bit version and -i386 is the 32 bit version for very old or very lightweight systems. Almost all systems in last 10 years are 64 bit and last 5 years UEFI.

Comment: @zondo No errors

Comment: @oldfred Good point - Downloading the x64 now. Any idea how to make sure the disk is bootable? Is it simply about placing the files there, or do I need to make some format / partition change?

Comment: Is PC UEFI? If so there is a simple way to make a UEFI only bootable flash drive. You just need it to be FAT32 with boot flag & extracted copy of all files from ISO. UEFI boots from /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi which will be there. All the other install apps do that but then also add syslinux for BIOS boot. Do not know if Mac is same or not. http://askubuntu.com/questions/395879/how-to-create-uefi-only-bootable-usb-live-media